# How to move SSRS mobile report (Mobile Report Publisher) from one server to another?

Tags: ssrs-2016

I have created a mobile report with a dataset from Server A (dev). I know want to move that report to Server B (prod). Is there a way to do this? When I open the report in Report Publisher and do Save As -> Server I am unable to select a different server.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bit of an oversight with SSRS Mobile reports. In order to change the dataset from a prod server to a dev server; I have found it easier to upload the datasets to the production server using the same folder structure as the dev server. The mobile report can then be uploaded and it will pick up the newly uploaded dataset.

After this you are free to move the datasets around without causing issues with the reports.

An easy workaround, but quite cumbersome to do in bulk

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but have you considered trying migrating Mobile Reports using GitHub project called [ReportingServicesTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools)?  Basically the project is a collection of PowerShell commands, which lets you download content from Server A and then upload it to Server B. You can download the ReportingServicesTools module from [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools).

I wrote a blog post about how to do this [here](https://parthpsha.com/migrating-ssrs-2016-content-via-powershell/) along with other things.

```
# downloads MyMobileReport from server A to Downloads folder
Out-RsRestCatalogItem -ReportPortalUri http://serverA/reports -RestApiVersion v1.0 -RsItem "/MyMobileReport" -Destination C:\Users\admin\Downloads -Verbose

# uploads MyMobileReport from Downloads folder to server B
Write-RsRestCatalogItem -ReportPortalUri http://serverB/reports -RestApiVersion v1.0 -Path C:\Users\admin\Downloads\MyMobileReport.rsmobile -RsFolder "/"
```