# Promoting SSRS 2016 Mobile Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am looking for a solution for promoting SSRS 2016 Mobile reports and their associated data sets between environments. Given that the link between the mobile report and the Shared Datasets is based on a GUID, I don't believe that it is possible to do this manually. Losing the Dataset breaks the Mobile reports rendering it inoperable - so you can't repoint it manually.

Does anyone know of a tool which may be able to assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405245/2310818. Basically there are PowerShell commands created for downloading and uploading individual items/folders from one server to another server. I think that will help you migrate Mobile Reports across servers.